# Python3 super().__init__() maximum recursion depth reached

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a multiple inheritance problem in python. Using python's super() command is giving me a "maximum recursion depth reached".
The code:

```
class program(object):
    def back(self):
    if self.currentWin == "welcome":
        self.welcomeWindow.root.destroy()
        exit(0)
    def login(self): print("login")
    def register(self): print("register")
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.currentWin = "welcome"
        self.welcomeWindow = welcomewin()

class welcomewin(program):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.root=tkinter.Tk()
        tkinter.Button(self.root,text="Exit",command=self.back).grid(row=1,column=2)
if __name__=="__main__": program()
```

The problem here is I'm trying to have a button inside welcomewin that calls program's back function, which it has inherited from program. However, it has not inherited the `currentwin` variable that back() relies on in order to decide what to do.
I get the following error if I run this code:

```
  File "E:/Python project/test.py", line 15, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "E:/Python project/test.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.welcomeWindow = welcomewin()
  File "E:/Python project/test.py", line 15, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "E:/Python project/test.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.welcomeWindow = welcomewin()
  File "E:/Python project/test.py", line 15, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "E:/Python project/test.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.welcomeWindow = welcomewin()
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
>>>
```

Comment: You call `welcomewin` which calls the `__init__` method of `program` which calls `welcomewin` which calls the `__init__` method of `program` which calls `welcomewin`.....

Comment: What is the purpose of inheriting `welcomwin` from `program`?

Answer (score 1):

It is only logical that you get this error. You inherit `welcomewin` from `program` and create a new `welcomewin` object in the `__init__()` function of `program`. This means a new `welcomewin` object will be created that calls the `__init__()` function again and this goes on forever.

Easy solution: Don't inherit welcomewin from program.

Answer (score -2):

You are calling init in init that's creating an infinite loop.

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

This should work

```
def __init__(self):
    super(program)
```

Comment: No, that's not going to help with the problem.

Comment: Calling `super().__init__()` is actually good practice as it calls the `__init__()` method of the base class. `super(program)` won't do anything at all.

Comment: seemed the likely cause of the infinity loop